# How can i await the subscribe method,which is called from other function

Tags: angular

I have subscribe method in one function to be reused,so i dont need to repeat everywhere the same thing.i want that function to be awaited so i can continue once when the result is received from the back end.In the clickEvent i get undefined because users are still not initialised because the subscribe method makes async operation.How can i solve this ?

```
  <button (click)="clickEvent()">Click button</button>

  clickEvent() {
    this.usersSubscribeHandler();
    console.log(this.users);
  }


usersSubscribeHandler() {
    this.testService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
    })
  }
```

Comment: why don't you want to use this.testService.getUsers() directly ? Are you using it somewhere else to reload the users ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use observables themselves? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

To unblock you quickly, you can convert the observable to a promise.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

async clickEvent() {
  this.users = await this.getUsers().pipe(take(1).toPromise();
  console.log(this.users);
}

getUsers() {
  return this.testService.getUsers();
}
```

That is if you like working with promises.

You can still keep it as an observable and subscribe in the click event.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

clickEvent() {
  this.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
    console.log(this.users);
  });
}

getUsers() {
  return this.testService.getUsers();
}
```